# "clock" font-awesome icon not showing on my webpage

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[I am supposed to make following webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df66c.png)

But when I am using font-awesome class to add clock icon highlighted in the image.Its not showing.
following is my code. Where  am i making mistake? thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Assignment1_2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style> 
  *{ font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}


  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class = "container">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Layout3</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
       </li>    
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>  
  </nav>

  <!--- navbar ends -->
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 pt-5">
       <h2>Blog Post Title</h2>
       <h5><small>by</small><span class = "text-primary"> Text</span></h5>
       <hr class="w-100 mx-auto">
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-4 pt-3" >
      <span class="d-xl-block px-4 py-3 rounded" style ="background-color: #e9ecef; border: 1px solid #ced4da">
       <h5 class="pt-0">Blog Search</h5>   
        <div class="input-group md-form form-sm pl-0 pb-2 pt-1">
           <input class="form-control my-0 py-1 border-50 rounded-left  "style="border-left:2px solid #ced4da;     border-top:2px solid #ced4da; border-bottom:2px solid #ced4da; border-right:1px solid #ced4da" type="text"  aria-label="Search">
           <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text bg-light border-50 border-left-0 rounded-right"style="border-width: 2px" id="basic-text1"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
           </div>
        </div>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 pt-5">
     <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I am using font-awesome class to add clock icon highlighted in the image.Its not showing.
following is my code. Where  am i making mistake? thanks in advance

Comment: Try `fa fa-clock-o`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use

```
<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
```

as you are using fontawesome 4.7

in fontawesome 5 they have used `far` class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Assignment1_2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style> 
  *{ font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}


  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class = "container">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Layout3</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
       </li>    
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>  
  </nav>

  <!--- navbar ends -->
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 pt-5">
       <h2>Blog Post Title</h2>
       <h5><small>by</small><span class = "text-primary"> Text</span></h5>
       <hr class="w-100 mx-auto">
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-4 pt-3" >
      <span class="d-xl-block px-4 py-3 rounded" style ="background-color: #e9ecef; border: 1px solid #ced4da">
       <h5 class="pt-0">Blog Search</h5>   
        <div class="input-group md-form form-sm pl-0 pb-2 pt-1">
           <input class="form-control my-0 py-1 border-50 rounded-left  "style="border-left:2px solid #ced4da;     border-top:2px solid #ced4da; border-bottom:2px solid #ced4da; border-right:1px solid #ced4da" type="text"  aria-label="Search">
           <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text bg-light border-50 border-left-0 rounded-right"style="border-width: 2px" id="basic-text1"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
           </div>
        </div>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 pt-5">
     <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
      
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please help me with one more thing. How to get that stylish "multiply X" in 900X300. I am unable to find any google font matching that style or also any fontawsome icon for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the following script in `<head></head>`

```
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
```

Comment: Could you please help me with one more thing. How to get that stylish "multiply X" in 900X300. I am unable to find any google font matching that style or also any fontawsome icon for that.

Comment: @Lotus Does it fix your issue